# how to pass a folder from a data lake store as a parameter to a pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

In data factory, I know you can pass a parameter at the beginning of a pipeline, and then access it later using @pipeline(). If I have a folder in a data lake store, how can I pass that as a parameter and have access to it later (let's say I want to loop a for-each over each file inside it.) Do I pass the path to the folder? Am I passing it as an object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the steps that you can use -

1. You can use pass folder path as a parameter (string) to the pipeline.
2. Use the path and "Get Metadata" activity with "Child Items". This will return the list of files in JSON Format

   [Get Metadata Selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zONRd.png)
3. Loop through using "Foreach" activity and perform any action.

   Use output from metadata activity as Items in Foreach activity (example below)

> @activity('Get List of Files').output

Hope this helps

Comment: how do you get the path to a data lake store? It doesn't have a normal path like a file on your computer. It has a URL. Do you pass it that?

Comment: Have you created a linked service to data lake store? If not, start there. You will have to create a linked service and then specify path starting from root foler e.g. "Folder1/subfoldera". You do not need to specify data lake url in dataset, it comes from linked service.

Answer (score 1):

1. First, you need create a data lake store linked service. It will contain the path of azure data lake store. You could use azure data factory UI to create the linked service
2. Then you need create a data lake store dataset reference that linked service in step 2.
3. Then you create a getMetaData activity reference dataset in step 2.
4. Then following steps provided by summit.

All of these can be done in UI.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-portal#create-a-pipeline